# The wordpress site is working well but whenever I open my wordpress dashboard, the dashboard not loaded properly

Tags: php, wordpress

The site is working well but whenever I open my admin panel first time dashboard looking like [Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8gSP.png) 
Now after this, if I reload the page my site got this error:You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.

And now I can not open any page after that.

Now if i clear my cache then my website is displayed

My .htaccess

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By7-gVeS797ISE1WdnZYTHI0MjQ

Comment: this is the permission issue or some code is taking the bit long time to execute. Check the folder permission and file permission folder must be 755 and file must be 644. Share .htacess code as well please

Comment: permissions all are set to folder:755

Comment: and file are set :644

Comment: Share .htacess code

Comment: Which .htaccess file have you attached a screenshot of? Your sites root .htaccess or your /wp-admin .htaccess? Also, if you view the source of the broken /wp-admin page, where do the .css files etc point to?

Comment: attached the root .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try with below .htacees

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: try with new one hoping your wordpress is on root directory

Comment: also try with this htaccess the problem is still

Comment: try to disable all plugins and let me know if it is resolving the issue. Just rename plugins folder

Comment: i have already try to rename the plugins folder to plugin-old

Comment: No issue, just not opening the website properly

Comment: your admin issue is resolved by doing that am i right?

Comment: in my website I have no issue is opening well every single page opens, Just not opening the admin

Comment: let's create a chat group so we can discuss

Comment: i haven't any reputation so i couldn't able to use chat